# spring default property values always default to second

Tags: java, spring

When defaulting values in a Spring XML configuration file with the following snippet:

```
<util:properties id="defaultConfiguration">
    <prop key="test.value">${first.value:notFilledIn}</prop>
</util:properties>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="defaultConfiguration" order="605" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

With the following properties being loaded:

```
first.value=first
second.value=second
```

The value always comes back as the "default" value, not the first key.

```
@Value("${test.value}")
private String theValue;
.....
System.out.println("theValue: " + theValue);
```

Output:

```
theValue: notFilledIn
```

If I change the prop value in the XML config to:

```
<prop key="test.value">${first.value}</prop>
```

The value comes back as expected:

```
theValue: first
```

Why is the default value always being pulled, when the "key" to the first value exists?

Comment: 'With the following properties being loaded'

How are you loading them?

Also what version of spring are you using? The meaning of context:property-placeholder differs by version

Comment: what happens if you dont use default value at all? Does it inject proper one or throws exception? Maybe property placeholder is loaded too late in context?

Comment: I am using Spring 4.0.8. The last example above shows what happens with no default value. A single property lookup works just fine (without a default).

Comment: Properties (first.value and last.value) are being loaded as such:
    <context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath:com/test/testing.properties"
  order="1000"  />  
This is loaded prior to the other items above. Again, works with either value standalone, just not when using the colon "default", as it only always takes the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I hope this helps anyone.

make sure you only have one

```
<context:property-placeholder>
```

in your code, otherwise they override each other
and your keys will not be set

Comment: No. You can have many. The "order" attribute controls what order they load in.

Comment: My question above was related to the "default" value (colon separator) not getting processed.

Comment: @LetsBeFrank did you solve it ? I have the same prboelm